# how do I put 2 functions together and make it work as I want in javascript and html5

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a game in which I have to put 100 buttons in a web and touch the start game which will be in the random numbers.

If I touch it, I win but, I have already done it,

They are ordered 1,2,3.... 98,99,100 but now I have to shuffle it.

I have the shuffle function made but I am trying to fuse it but it doesn't work.

It works in the console but I want to render it on the page.  See:

```
var arr = []

const doNotDuplicate = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var current = i
    if(arr.indexOf(current) < 0) {
      arr.push(current)

          var btn = document.createElement("button");
          var t = document.createTextNode(i);
          btn.appendChild(t);
          document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(btn) 
    }
  }  
  return arr
}
```

```js
function shuffle(arr) {
    var i, j, temp;
    for (i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));    
        swap(arr, i, j);
    }
    return arr;    
}
```

the swap is what it permits to change its position and shuffle the numbers

```js
function setup() {
    if(doNotDuplicate(arr)) {
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log(shuffle(arr))
            shuffle(arr)
        }, 1000
```

and this is the function I said before.

It works in the console but It does not work in the page.

Comment: Do you mean you want a swap to occur every second, and for the page to reflect the change? How do you put the elements on the page?

Comment: I think you are missing some code... can you please make sure the code posted is a [mcve] of the issue to troubleshoot?

Comment: here is basically all the main code

Comment: @blurfus The code is more clean. May u see again?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes! I want to see the shuffle function reflected on the page when I press a button which is already made

Comment: Makes sense.  Do you actually need an underlying Javascript array to switch around as well, or do you just want the visual effect of the elements switching positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either empty the HTML container and append the array elements again, or you can identify the children indicies and swap them with each other, or (as I'm doing below) collect all children into an array, shuffle that array, then call `appendChild` with those shuffled children:

```js
const arr = Array.from(
  { length: 100 },
  (_, i) => i + 1
);
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
// Append all buttons
for (const num of arr) {
  container.appendChild(document.createElement('button')).textContent = num;
}

const children = [...container.children];
start.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    // Shuffle children
      for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));    
        [children[i], children[j]] = [children[j], children[i]];
      }
      for (const child of children) {
        container.appendChild(child);
      }
  }, 1000);
}, { once: true });
```

```html
<div>
  <button id='start'>START</button>
</div>
<div id='container'>
  Press START to begin
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance. Your answer was really helpful. I have another question, May you help me? and thanks!

Comment: Another question? What's up?

Comment: Well I have already done the code everything runs well, but now I put a timer to calculate the time-to-click which will be the score, I know how to sort the scores, the thing is that I am a little confused with localStorage It doesnt work :/

Comment: If you want a persistent array of scores, when you want to add to the array, do something like `const arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.scores || []); arr.push(score); localStorage.scores = JSON.stringify(arr);`

Comment: Yeah sorry for being late. I was trying to resolve this, I get what you said but I don know why this still not working well.

Comment: If u may help me, It would be really helpful. Your code is awesome https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492598/what-am-i-doing-bad-with-localstorage