# What am I doing bad with localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a time-to-click score table but first I have to localstorage each time I get  in a game but I dont know how I have been trying everything but it still not working, I need to finish this fast, and I need help... otherwise I would try everyday to resolve this alone because I know that's the way to learn.. When I press the finished button It says that times.push() is not a function.

```
    let times = Array.from(
  { length: 3 }
)


        let interval2;

        // Timer CountUp
        const timerCountUp = () => { 
          let times = 0;
          let current = times;

          interval2 = setInterval(() => {
            times = current++
            saveTimes(times)
            return times
          },1000);
        }

        // Saves the times to localStorage
        const saveTimes = (times) => {
          localStorage.setItem('times', JSON.stringify(times))
        }


// Read existing notes from localStorage
const getSavedNotes = () => {
  const timesJSON = localStorage.getItem('times')

  try {
      return timesJSON ? JSON.parse(timesJSON) : []
  } catch (e) {
      return []
  }    
}

    //Button which starts the countUp
    start.addEventListener('click', () => {
      timerCountUp();
    })

    // Button which stops the countUp
    document.querySelector('#start_button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      console.log('click');
      times = getSavedNotes() 
      times.push({
        score: interval2
      })
      if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);   
        clearInterval(interval2); 
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the line `times = JSON.parse(localStorage.times || [])` to `times = JSON.parse(localStorage.times) || []` this makes sure that if the parsing fails it will still be an array.

Even better is wrap them with try-catch just in case if your JSON string is corrupted and check if the time is an array in the finally if not set it to empty array.

Comment: did you check if there is parse error with JSON.parse

Comment: you seem to be changing the type of times from array to number to timerId, use a different variable, and print the value you are storing to local storage before storing it.

Comment: I mean I didnt think it because I am just going to put 3 highscores levels First, second and third... so I thought an ID was not going to be necessary

Comment: Array here - `let times = Array.from({ length: 3 })` Integer here `const timerCountUp = () => { 
          let times = 0;
          let current = times;

          interval2 = setInterval(() => {
            times = current++
            saveTimes(times)
            return times
          },1000);
        }` so essentially you are storing a number and parsing it as json.

Comment: Yes but why It is not pushing my score to localStorage creating 3 diferents numbers?

Comment: when I press start to play again and it has already a score. It resets the previous score and starts in 0 again